# How to set the encode in PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xlsx?

Tags: encode, phpspreadsheet

I want to use PhpSpreadsheet convert xlsx to pdf, it's succeed.
But the Chinese word in xlsx is error.
And the setInputEncoding method is not found.
What can I do?  please give me guide

```
$reader = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xlsx();
$spreadsheet = $reader->load($public['root'].'/' . $fileName);
$writer = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Mpdf');
$pdfName = str_replace($extension, 'pdf', $fileName);
$writer->save($public['root'].'/' . $pdfName);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set Font Family in file xlsx.

```
$reader = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xlsx();
$spreadsheet = $reader->load($public['root'].'/' . $fileName);

$styleArray = array(
    'font'  => array(
        'name'  => 'Verdana' // change your font
    ));

$spreadsheet->getDefaultStyle()->applyFromArray($styleArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is fixed.
First I download the yahei.ttf and put it to mpdf/ttfonts.
Then regist it in mpdf/src/Config/FontVariables.php.
Finally find the line 41 at  PhpSpreadsheet/Writer/Pdf/Mypdf.php and change the code like this

```html
$pdf = $this->createExternalWriterInstance(array_merge($config, ['default_font' => 'yahei']));

$pdf->setDisplayMode('fullpage');
$pdf -> useAdobeCJK = TRUE;
$pdf ->autoScriptToLang = true;
$pdf -> autoLangToFont = true;
```